# Apertium + Python: POS-tagger not providing surface form

Tags: python, pos-tagger, morphological-analysis, transducer, apertium

I'm trying to POS-tag some sentences in Italian with Apertium's tagger.
While according to the [Apertium GitHub page](https://github.com/apertium/apertium-python) I am supposed to get as output also the surface form in addition to the morphological analysis, I only get the analysis. I want also the surface form. I cannot infer it since the tagger doesn't necessarily tag a single token, so I cannot simply tokenize the original sentence and loop over it or zip it with the tagger's output.

According to the GitHub page:

```
In [1]: import apertium
In [2]: tagger = apertium.Tagger('ita')
In [3]: tagger.tag('gatti').
Out[3]: [gatti/gatto<n><m><pl>]
```

What I got:

```
In [1]: import apertium
In [2]: tagger = apertium.Tagger('ita')
In [3]: tagger.tag('gatti') # 'gatti' is the surface form
Out[3]: [gatto<n><m><pl>]
```

How can I get the surface form? If I provided one token at a time this would not be a problem since I would know what the token is. But in a sentence I cannot know how the tagger creates chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when creating a tagger of language `ita` it looks for `/usr/share/apertium/modes/ita-tagger.mode`. This is a shell script that calls various apertium commands. The command for the Italian tagger script happens to be configured to not include surface commands (it's missing the `-p` option).

A quick and dirty solution is to just `sudo vim /usr/share/apertium/modes/ita-tagger.mode` (or `sudo nano` or whatever your editor is) and add `-p` to the end of the last command, so the file looks like

```
lt-proc -w '/usr/share/apertium/apertium-ita/ita.automorf.bin' | cg-proc '/usr/share/apertium/apertium-ita/ita.rlx.bin' | apertium-tagger -g $2 '/usr/share/apertium/apertium-ita/ita.prob' -p
```

and do `tagger = apertium.Tagger('ita')` again.

---

A sudo-less solution would be to copy the mode file, edit, and add it to the search path, see https://github.com/apertium/apertium-python#installing-more-modes-from-other-language-data

Comment: I know I should not use comments to thank people but I'm exploding with happiness and this was my first question ever on stackoverflow. I was intimidated and actually not very hopeful to get an answer. I was so wrong. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: No problem =D Note that there's also the #apertium IRC channel on freenode if you have stuff that doesn't feel like it fits on stackoverflow :-)